# Global vars and function in an include file PHP

Tags: php, function, global-variables

I am trying to resize an image's size and then putting it in a FancyBox.
I've managed to do so in another page and I imitated it to the other page, and the functions wont work.

This is the code in the not working page (it has 2 vars for width and height, and the resizeImage function gets to them by declaring "global ;", however it wont work).

*Note- both pages: the one that's working and the one that doesn't are on the same folder so all paths are the same.

```
include("Include/FunctionsPHP.php"); //Includes the ResizeImage functions
$outputHeight;
$outputWidth; 

$index=$row["nIndex"];
$picture="products/pictures/{$row["sPicture"]}";

ResizeImage(450,400,$picture);
```

And this is the Include file:

```
function ResizeImage($maxWidth,$maxHeight,$picture)
{
    GLOBAL $outputWidth;
    GLOBAL $outputHeight;
    $size = getimagesize($picture);

    if ($size) {
        $imageWidth  = $size[0];
        $imageHeight = $size[1];
        $wRatio = $imageWidth / $maxWidth;
        $hRatio = $imageHeight / $maxHeight;
        $maxRatio = max($wRatio, $hRatio);
        $outputWidth = $imageWidth / $maxRatio;
        $outputHeight = $imageHeight / $maxRatio;
        echo $outputHeight."\t";
        echo $outputWidth;
    }
}
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How exactly it "won't work"? What are the values of the variables inside the function? (That said, you probably shouldn't be using global variables in the first place, try passing those values as parameters to your function.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the two variables as parameters to your function.

Comment: Like `function ResizeImage($maxWidth,$maxHeight,$picture,&$outputWidth,&$oH)`. This is _passing-by-reference_.

Comment: Didn't see the "&" of the reference :D That worked.. Thanks alot!